# What's the best way to backup cPanel WHM server to Amazon S3?

Tags: backup, amazon-s3

I would like to archive cPanel backups to Amazon S3 instead of FTP.

I've done some googling, but I'm not finding anything authoritative.

I found the following options:

1. [whms3backup.com](http://whms3backup.com/) - $250 for Unlimited Licenses
2. [List of S3 Backup scripts in cPanel Application Catalog](http://applications.cpanel.net/?s=s3%20backup&cat=select%20a%20category&x=0&y=0)
3. [Manual setup using s3tools](http://fiddyp.co.uk/cpanel-backups-to-amazon-s3/)

**What do you think? What do you recommend or not recommend?**

Answer (score 2):

I have not worked with cPanel but what I understand is that it is a bunch of static files (your website) and then the MySQL database.

You could install s3cmd tool -- http://s3tools.org/s3cmd on your server and use this tool to backup your website tar file and mysql dump tar file to S3.

You can write all of this in a simple bash script and run it via cron.

Comment: I listed this option as option 3. I'm looking for feedback from people who already have experience with these options not ideas on how it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

We use s3backupwhm.com which seems to work really well. Got it running on 3 of our WHM servers with no real issues. No idea why S3 support isn't a core part of WHM yet!

Comment: s3backupwhm.com and whms3backup.com mentioned by the OP are the same service.

Answer (score 0):

Login to WHM and go to "Configure Backup."  All the way at the bottom are the options for the backup destination.  You can choose either FTP or a destination on the local filesystem (for example "/root/backups").  Chose the local filesystem and then just configure s3cmd to run via a cron job to replicate that directory to S3.

`/root/s3cmd/s3cmd sync --recursive --delete-removed /root/backups/cpbackup/daily s3://rbn-cpanel/daily_backups`

Each backed-up CPanel account is a separate gzipped tarball so it makes this pretty easy.